# Attempt to add a custom rule to output which already has a custom rule

Tags: cmake, bison, flex-lexer

I am using cmake to compile a library using flex & bison and I have this error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindBISON.cmake:279 (add_custom_command):
  Attempt to add a custom rule to output

  PATH/automaton.c.rule

  which already has a custom rule.
```

Here is the content of my CMakeLists meant to compile it.

```
FIND_PACKAGE(BISON REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(FLEX REQUIRED)

flex_target(lexer automaton_lexer.l ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/automaton.c)
bison_target(parser automaton_parser.y ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/automaton.c)
add_flex_bison_dependency(lexer parser)

add_library(automaton automaton.c queue.c tikz_handler.c ${FLEX_lexer_OUTPUTS} ${BISON_parser_OUTPUTS})
target_link_libraries(automaton ${FLEX_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(automaton PUBLIC headers)
```

I believe, I followed the documentation, yet I can't figure why it fails.
Could anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify different output files for flex and bison targets.

```
flex_target(lexer automaton_lexer.l ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lexer.c)
bison_target(parser automaton_parser.y ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/parser.c)
```

Comment: Thanks. I must have been confused on the signature of the function. But then how do I specify a source file to be compiled with (my automaton.c).

Comment: According to [this](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/modern/c/software/flex/flex.html#SEC5) you would couple it by an additional include that exposes your declarations. See `%{ #include <math.h> %}` section

Comment: flex/bison only generate the files, adding `automaton.c` to your `add_library` command as you already do should be sufficient.